# Why does Html.Label() not work with periods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm outputting a fews strings using Html.Label(strings).

When I pass it a value with a period in it, it outputs nothing but spaces

Html.Label(company)

e.g `<%: Html.Label("Bill Co.")%>`

Company is a  dynamic value, it will work if the value is "Bill Co" but not if it is "Bill Co.", the only difference is that period.

I should be able to pass any string to it as per 
HhtmlHelper.Label via msdn

```
  public IHtmlString Label(
        string labelText
    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: because mircosoft sux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used ToHtmlString() and that solved the issue.

Thanks

Comment: used `ToHtmlString()` how with `Html.Label()` ?

Comment: No by itself <%: company.ToHtmlString() %>

Answer (score 27):

You can also use

```
<%= Html.Label("","Bill Co.")%>
```

When using `Html.label()`, the parameter needs to be an expression that identifies the property to display and the for attribute.

Comment: That saved me a lot of time! Thanks. **Note:**  You can use this in Razor syntax too, i.e. `@Html.Label("", "Bill Co.")` - and it will work (of course, you can also use properties here, like: `@Html.Label("", myObj.FirmName)`. It just needs to be in scope.

Comment: I can't believe I've never run into this before... or how many things out there will disappear if someone includes a period in the text. Scary

Answer (score 4):

When using [**Html.label()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310185%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), the parameter needs to be an expression that identifies the property to display. I don't think there is a property in your model named `Bill Co.`.

You need to specify it like this:

```
<%: Html.Label("Name")%>
```

or this:

```
<%: Html.Label(model => model.Name)%>
```

If you just need to output a constant value as a label use the `<label>` tag:

```
<label>Bill Co.</label>
```

Comment: Its dynamic value, it will work if the value is "Bill Co" but not if it is "Bill Co.", the only difference is that period.

Comment: @Fabii: You are still using the helper incorrectly. You are not suppose to use it like that for just a constant string as it will try and interpret it as a property name. That it works if you don't specify a `.`is incidentally. I linked the documentation as well which also states it expects an expression that identifies the property to display.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but since learning asp.net core means googling a lot, I chime in with a solution:

```
@Model.yourVar
```

Lots of examples are using @Html.DisplayName(Model.yourVar) and what-not. Except DisplayName() is not meant for displaying simple strings, and the docs are one-liners with no examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple label tag :

`<label>Bill co.</label>`